# Offline анализатор access и error логов от nginx: вытащить ОС, браузер, количество посетителей

Tags: ubuntu, логирование

Есть куча логов с сервера. Как и чем их можно на локальном хосте проанализировать? Интересуют ОС, браузеры, количество посетителей. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Каких именно логов?

Comment: access и error от nginx`а

Comment: https://goaccess.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно поставить любую систему анализа логов, скопировать логи себе и натравить систему на логи.

Например:

- [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)
- [splunk](https://www.splunk.com/)

А можно, просто на баша/перле/или даже пхп написать в пару строк с регулярками и вытянуть все, что нужно. Например, есть логи nginx и хотим узнать популярность по браузерам.

```
egrep -o -h '"[^"]*"$' access.log* | sort | uniq -c  | sort -n -k 1
```

разбираем по пайпам (вертикальная палочка)

- вначале egrep вытягивает концы строк - в моих логах user agent записан в самом конце в двойных кавычках. А искать во всех файлах access.log. параметр `-h` говорит не выводить имена файлов - они только будут мешать.
- потом это все отсортируем, так как дальше будет uniq -c, который посчитает дубликаты и выведет их кол-во. Но ему нужен отсортированный список.
- и в конце ещё раз отсортируем список. Параметр `-k 1` говорит, что сортировать нужно по первому столбцу (там у нас кол-во), а `-n` говорит, что нужно применять сортировку как для чисел (по умолчанию там лексикографическая и числа будут сортироваться так 1 11 2 вместо ожидаемого 1 2 11).

Но что, если интересуют именно операционные системы? тут чуточку сложнее, потому что нужно будет надеятся, что браузеры правильно передают ее. А боты обычно подсовывают левое. Только доделать регулярку.

Или хочется статистику по айпи адресам. Тут также просто - айпи идут первыми в строке до пробела (мы все ещё говорим о логах nginx, настроенных по умолчанию).

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' access.log* | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n
```

Вытягивать кол-во пользователй - а вот тут уже действительно проблема. Нужно для начала понять, как именно их считать. Если Вы позаботились, и в лог выводите какую то уникальную информацию (например, сессионную куку или имя пользователя фигурирует в урл) - нет проблем. Подбираем регулярку для вырезания и готово.

Часто логи бывают упакованы в архив. И тут их даже распаковывать не нужно. Для многих утилит существует их "аналог", который начинается с  буквы z. То есть, если cat умеет выводить просто текстовый файл, то zcat умеет выводить файл, запакованный в архив. А zgrep ищет в них.

Так как логи обычно резко не меняются, то подобные системы имеют право на жизнь  в своих маленьких проектах. В больших Энтерпрайзах лучше использовать вышеприведенные системы, которые будут в режиме реального времени логи парсить и позволять делать различные запросы и нотификации.

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ!